# Android-Studio: There is no "Java" Folder in my projects

Tags: java, android-studio

I had downloaded and installed Android Studio before installing JDK 8. I'm totally a beginner in Android development. At first, I didn't know that I have to download JDK first.

I watched many tutorials for making my first Android app. In those videos, they are using a folder named **java** that is a sub-folder of **App**. But in my **App** Folder, there is no **Java** named folder.

Now I've Installed JDK 8 But still, there is no **Java** named Folder.

So please tell me how to get access to that **Java** Folder? So that I can do further studies of Android development.

Comment: What is the complete directory structure of your project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you need to dig a little deeper. The "java" folder is located at `app/src/main/java`.

Comment: Ohhk... Thanks for your answer..  But... are they both same or not??( app/java and app/src/main/java )

Comment: @TheBrainiacs Since the tutorial you are using leaves out small, yet important, details like this, I suggest you find a different one. Good luck with your programming journey!

Comment: @TheBrainiacs The best way to thank someone who answers your question on this site is to accept the answer by clicking the checkmark. Please do so when the system allows you to. When you have enough rep, you can also vote for any answers which you find useful.

Comment: Thank you so much, Can you please tell me a perfect tutorial for Android Studio? And from where you learned Android Studio??

Comment: @TheBrainiacs I suggest starting with the official tutorials from Google at http://developer.android.com/.

Comment: Whether or not you use these tutorials, you definitely must become familiar with the documentation there as you learn Android programming. It will answer almost all of your beginner questions.